# In TypeScript, is it better to annotate a function's return value when it is defined or at the call site?

Tags: function

I've been learning TypeScript for about 6 months and noticing the large amount of freedom it gives you in developing an annotation strategy.

Let's say I have

```js
async function createItemInDb(itemData: IItemData): Promise<IItem> {
 // runs some async code and then returns the newly created item
}
```

and I call the function elsewhere in my code

```js
const createdItem: IItem = await createItemInDb(itemData)
```

In general, is it better to annotate a function's return type when it is defined or at the call site?

What are situations where one would make more sense over the other? Or perhaps annotate in both places?

I was reading it's better to annotate less and let the compiler naturally infer types.
[On Writing Less TypeScript](https://betterprogramming.pub/typescript-with-fewer-types-f7fa636476db). Would it ever make sense to define the return type in neither position?

The question is in regards to functions in TypeScript in general and not just the code example shown.

Thank you very much for taking a look this and helping out a TypeScript nooby.

Comment: TypeScript can infer most of the types. You probably don't need to annotate it here.

Comment: @catgirlkelly Also, I understand there are cases where TypeScript is not needed because TypeScript can infer types. Is there a use case for putting them in anyway for documentation or to prevent future unintended changes?

Comment: @tendermusings - the compiler is always smarter than you. The compiler is the thing that prevents future unintended changes, not your specifically declared return type. It's superfluous in 99% of cases. As for the other 1%, I'm not sure what they would be, but they probably exist.